# Drupal.Behavior fires multiple times while logged in

Tags: javascript, 9

Some of my Drupal behaviors are firing multiple times while as a logged-in user:

```
(function myFunction (Drupal) {
  "use strict";
  Drupal.behaviors.myBehavior = {
    attach: function attach (context) {

      console.log("Hello world");
    }
  };
}(Drupal));
```

The above will log "Hello world" multiple times in console while logged in, only once while logged out.

I've been working through updating scripts to use Drupal's `once()` library, but am unsure if this is the fix or just a patch.

Is there a higher context I could look at that might be causing this? I'm unsure of the difference between logged-in and logged-out here.

Answer (score 1):

`Drupal.behaviors` does not only fire on page load, it fires on ajax calls or whenever new elements are inserted into the DOM. The `once` library is built to handle this - you attach handlers to only fire a single time.

You can read more about using `once` here: https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview